# Finding all possible combination of a vector

Tags: r, string, combinations

I have a vector `v = c("abc", "csb", "csfd", "dds", "edds")` of strings.
I want to produce all possible combinations less than or equal to length n using elements of vector v.

I tried `combn` function which gave result something like this

```
>>combn(v,2)

     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10] 
[1,] "abc" "abc"  "abc" "abc"  "csb"  "csb" "csb"  "csfd" "csfd" "dds" 
[2,] "csb" "csfd" "dds" "edds" "csfd" "dds" "edds" "dds"  "edds" "edds"
```

But I want combination of duplicate strings and lower degree term as well. For example, if n = 2 then output should be like

```
     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  [,4]   [,5]   [,6]  [,7]   [,8]   [,9]   [,10] 
[1,] "abc" "csb" "csfd" "dds" "edds" "abc" "abc"  "abc"  "abc"  " csb"  
[2,] ""      ""     ""    ""    ""   "abc" "csb" "csfd"  "edds" "edds"
```

and other terms.

Comment: Try `n <- 2; lapply(seq(n), function(i) combn(v,i))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We loop through the sequence of 'n' with `lapply`, specify the 'm' in `combn` as the looped value, get the transpose of `combn` output, convert to `data.frame` and then `rbind` the elements of `list` using `rbindlist` (from `data.table`) with `fill=TRUE`.

```
library(data.table)
n <- 2
lst <- lapply(seq(n), function(i) as.data.frame(t(combn(v,i))))
rbindlist(lst, fill=TRUE)
#      V1   V2
# 1:  abc   NA
# 2:  csb   NA
# 3: csfd   NA
# 4:  dds   NA
# 5: edds   NA
# 6:  abc  csb
# 7:  abc csfd
# 8:  abc  dds
# 9:  abc edds
#10:  csb csfd
#11:  csb  dds
#12:  csb edds
#13: csfd  dds
#14: csfd edds
#15:  dds edds
```

---

If we need all the combinations use `expand.grid`

```
lst <- lapply(seq(n), function(i) expand.grid(rep(list(v), i)))
rbindlist(lst, fill=TRUE)
#    Var1 Var2
# 1:  abc   NA
# 2:  csb   NA
# 3: csfd   NA
# 4:  dds   NA
# 5: edds   NA
# 6:  abc  abc
# 7:  csb  abc
# 8: csfd  abc
# 9:  dds  abc
#10: edds  abc
#11:  abc  csb
#12:  csb  csb
#13: csfd  csb
#14:  dds  csb
#15: edds  csb
#16:  abc csfd
#17:  csb csfd
#18: csfd csfd
#19:  dds csfd
#20: edds csfd
#21:  abc  dds
#22:  csb  dds
#23: csfd  dds
#24:  dds  dds
#25: edds  dds
#26:  abc edds
#27:  csb edds
#28: csfd edds
#29:  dds edds
#30: edds edds
```

Comment: But this doesn't contains repeated term like abc and abc etc. See 6th column in in desired output.